# Conditionally Run Google Sheets Custom Function

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets-custom-function

I have developed a custom function in Google Sheets which is consuming a paid API. The problem is every time the sheet is opened the function refreshes (normal Google Sheets behavior). How can I work around that?

> How can the function run only in case the arguments change?

If that is not the case it should preserve the previous result.

---

```
/**
 * Gets distances
 *
 * @param {string} postalcode The origin
 * @param {string} apikey The Google API key
 * @param {Array} cities The destinations
 * @return The distances
 * @customfunction
 */
function C_GETDIST(postalcode, apikey, cities){
  if(postalcode == "")
    return "";

  var placeid = GETPID(postalcode,apikey);

  if(placeid == null)
    return "NO RESULTS GEO-CODING API";

  cities = cities.filter(function(city){ return city[0] !== "" ? true : false }).map(function(city){ return city[0].split(" ").join("+") });
  cities = cities.join('|');

  var d = new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
  d.setHours(9);
  var time = Math.round(d/1000);

  var endpoint = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json";
  var query_basic = "origins=place_id:" + placeid
                    + "&"
                    + "destinations=" + encodeURIComponent(cities)
                    + "&"
                    + "arrival_time=" + time
                    + "&"
                    + "key=" + apikey;
  var query_transit = "mode=transit&transit_mode=rail";

  var requests = [
    endpoint + "?" + query_basic,
    endpoint + "?" + query_basic + "&" + query_transit
  ];  

  var responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);

  var distances_durations = [];
  for(var i = 0;i < responses.length; i++){
    var response = JSON.parse(responses[i].getContentText());
    if(!i)
      response["rows"][0]["elements"].map(function(element,index){          
        distances_durations[index] = element["status"] === "OK" ? [element["distance"]["value"],element["duration"]["value"]] : ["",""];
      },distances_durations)
    else
      response["rows"][0]["elements"].map(function(element,index){
        if(element["status"] === "OK")          
          distances_durations[index].push(element["distance"]["value"],element["duration"]["value"]);
        else
          distances_durations[index].push("",""); 
      },distances_durations)
  }

  return distances_durations
}

/**
 * Gets place id
 *
 * @param {string} postalcode Postal code
 * @param {string} apikey The Google API key
 * @return The place id
 */
function GETPID(postalcode, apikey){
  var endpoint = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";
  var query = "address=united%20kingdom&components=postal_code:";  

  var request = endpoint 
                + "?" 
                + query 
                + encodeURIComponent(postalcode) 
                + "&key=" 
                + apikey;

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(request);

  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return json["status"] === "OK" ? [json["results"][0]["place_id"]] : null; // added as an array item 
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Could you also please indicate which all are the parameters you're referring to while indicating `in case the arguments changes`? It would also help if you could share a dummy sheet that utilises this script so folks could devise a solution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Properties service to store the previous value and some kind of flag to tell to your custom function when if should take the value stored in the corresponding properties store and when should get it from the paid API.

Related

- [Make a simple counter in Google Scripts which keeps track of previous value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62418854/1595451)